# How do I put a report into a form in Access 2007

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2007

In Access 2007 how do I put a report into a form? In other words I have a form and I want a report to be visible within it. I've done this before but I've forgotten how to do it; I also come up with nothing when I Google it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to figure this out; while yes it is not possible to put a report into a form, it is possible to make a form mimic a report (this was what I had done in the past). When I say mimic a report, I a mean it acts just like one including pagination. To do this I used the form wizard and walked through it using a linked table as the basis; I then changed the data source for the form to be based off of a query. And lastly of course forms can easily be embedded into forms.

Comment: It is possible to add a report into a form.  Its quite easy.. Do you need to know how??

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, this ability and feature arrived in Access 2010, and you don't have this ability to embed a report in a form in a2007.